# Why do cursors overlap when using printf() with gotoxy function?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm making Tetris.

I used gotoxy function to make the wall.

But when I make a horizontal line, it keeps getting cut in half.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    COORD Pos;
    Pos.X = x;
    Pos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Pos);
}

void drawMap() {
    int h, w;

    for (h = 0; h < 10; h++) {
        for (w = 0; w < 10; w++) {
            gotoxy(w, h);
            printf("□"); //□ is a special character.
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result.

[image]

However, if you copy and paste and check, the output is correct.

Why does this happen?

Comment: related issue https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/52#issuecomment-977217938

Comment: @jay The issue is unrelated to the Windows Terminal. There's no indication that the Windows Terminal is involved here at all. It's far more likely that mixing `printf` with [console API functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) doesn't produce the desired effect. Try using `WriteFile` or `WriteConsole` in place of `printf`.